# How do I exit recursion after append/3 in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, append

```
    door_between(bed_room, hidden_chamber).
    door_between(hidden_chamber, basement).       

    rev(L,R) :- my_reverse(L,[],R).
    my_reverse([H|T],A,R) :- my_reverse(T,[H|A],R).
    my_reverse([],A,A).

    path_from(Src,Dest,Path) :-
         path_from(Src,Dest,[],Path),
         rev(Path,Z),
         append(Src,Z,Z).

     path_from(S,S,P,P).
     path_from(S,D,P,NV) :-
         (door_between(S,A) ; door_between(A,S)),
         \+ member(A,P),
         path_from(A, D, [A|P], NV).
```

This is my code to find a path in an un-directed graph of rooms. It seems to get to the correct result during recursion but calls *Redo at a point and I do not understand why, here is the trace.

```
path_from(bed_room,basement,X).
 * Call: (8) path_from(bed_room, basement, _12282) ? creep
 * Call: (9) path_from(bed_room, basement, [], _12282) ? creep
   Call: (10) door_between(bed_room, _12624) ? creep
   Exit: (10) door_between(bed_room, hidden_chamber) ? creep
   Call: (10) lists:member(hidden_chamber, []) ? creep
   Fail: (10) lists:member(hidden_chamber, []) ? creep
 * Redo: (9) path_from(bed_room, basement, [], _12282) ? creep
 * Call: (10) path_from(hidden_chamber, basement, [hidden_chamber], _12282) ? creep
   Call: (11) door_between(hidden_chamber, _12630) ? creep
   Exit: (11) door_between(hidden_chamber, basement) ? creep
   Call: (11) lists:member(basement, [hidden_chamber]) ? creep
   Fail: (11) lists:member(basement, [hidden_chamber]) ? creep
 * Redo: (10) path_from(hidden_chamber, basement, [hidden_chamber], _12282) ? creep
 * Call: (11) path_from(basement, basement, [basement, hidden_chamber], _12282) ? creep
 * Exit: (11) path_from(basement, basement, [basement, hidden_chamber], [basement, hidden_chamber]) ? creep
 * Exit: (10) path_from(hidden_chamber, basement, [hidden_chamber], [basement, hidden_chamber]) ? creep
 * Exit: (9) path_from(bed_room, basement, [], [basement, hidden_chamber]) ? creep
   Call: (9) rev([basement, hidden_chamber], _12636) ? creep
   Call: (10) my_reverse([basement, hidden_chamber], [], _12638) ? creep
   Call: (11) my_reverse([hidden_chamber], [basement], _12644) ? creep
   Call: (12) my_reverse([], [hidden_chamber, basement], _12650) ? creep
   Exit: (12) my_reverse([], [hidden_chamber, basement], [hidden_chamber, basement]) ? creep
   Exit: (11) my_reverse([hidden_chamber], [basement], [hidden_chamber, basement]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) my_reverse([basement, hidden_chamber], [], [hidden_chamber, basement]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) rev([basement, hidden_chamber], [hidden_chamber, basement]) ? creep
```

**Call: (9) lists:append(bed_room, [hidden_chamber, basement], [hidden_chamber, basement]) ? creep**

```
    * Redo: (11) path_from(basement, basement, [basement, hidden_chamber], _12282) ? creep
      Call: (12) door_between(basement, _12636) ?
```

(The bolded line that breaks the code block is the line I'm concerned about, and it's triggered by append(Src,Z,Z) in path_from/3.) At the **Call: (9)** to append, that resulting list is the answer that I want for this particular test case, I'm assuming append would return [bed_room, hidden_chamber, basement], but the next thing is a *Redo and I'm really confused as to why, am I just confused on the concept of recursion? I think I just need a tiny nudge and I can wrap my head around it.

Comment: Note that `append(Src,Z,Z).` will necessarily fail unless `Src = []` since the only list appended to `Z` that yields `Z` would be the empty list.

Comment: Thank you, I've spent so long on this, I really appreciate the nudge.

Comment: The other issue is that, `append(bed_room, [hidden_chamber, basement], [hidden_chamber, basement])` has a first argument that isn't even a list. In normal usage scenarios, `append/3` requires all the arguments to be a list. What do you want to do with `Z`? It doesn't appear in your argument list.

Comment: It may not help you in this case, but often when you see the answer in the recursive call but are not able to obtain it as a result, it means you have omitted a "return variable" argument and you just need to add one and assign to it only in the final step.